Sample mean of Bernoulli trials is admissible under squared loss
Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli trials with probability $\theta\in(0,1)$, and let $L:(0,1)\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be the squared loss function, i.e. $L(\theta,a)=(\theta-a)^2$. I am trying to show that the sample mean $d(\mathbf{X})=\overline{X}$ is an admissible decision rule, i.e. there does not exist a decision rule $d':\{0,1\}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $R(\theta,d')\leq R(\theta,d)$ for all $\theta$, and $R(\theta,d')<R(\theta,d)$ for some $\theta$. Here, $R(\theta,d)$ denotes the risk, defined by
$$R(\theta,d)=E(L(\theta,d(\mathbf{X})))=E(\theta-d(\mathbf{X}))^2.$$
I feel like there should be a straight forward way to show this, but I am not seeing it. I have shown that given a prior distribution $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ on $\theta$, I showed that the Bayes estimator is $d_{\alpha,\beta}(\mathbf{X})=\frac{\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\alpha+\beta+n}$. I believe being a Bayes estimator in this case implies that $d_{\alpha,\beta}$ is an admissible decision rule. Then, taking the limit $\alpha,\beta\to 0$, we get $d_{\alpha,\beta}(\mathbf{X})\to\overline{X}$, so if I could claim that a limit of admissible decision rules is admissible, I would be done. But I don't think this is true in general. Any ideas?
Edit: Cross-posted to CrossValidated
